# EdmRelationshipAttribute error in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am experiencing the following error when I try to assign a new reference to a navigation property. So far, all of my searching has not really turned up anything useful, so I was wondering if I might get any help from SO on this.

> Metadata information for the
>   relationship
>   'CustomerModel.FK_Execution_ClientBlock'
>   could not be retrieved. Make sure that
>   the EdmRelationshipAttribute for the
>   relationship has been defined in the
>   assembly

What is strange is that all of my code works. This is only occurring during a unit test. I assume it's because I'm using a mocking framework (MOQ) to mock up this particular EF object.

We're using the version of EF that comes with .net 3.5 if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously had a similar problem, in my case the solution was this: [MetadataException when using Entity Framework Entity Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074337/metadataexception-when-using-entity-framework-entity-connection)

Basically you need to add the name of the dll to the metadata connection string