# Why am I getting this error 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException occurred '

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

This is my code:

```
public List<Core.Domain.ActivityDepreciationType> GetAllActivityDepreciationType()
    {
        using (TrenStarEAMEntities1 dbContext = new TrenStarEAMEntities1())
        {
            // Exception occurs here --v
            var efActivityDepriciationType = dbContext.ActivityDepreciationTypes.ToList();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<EFModels.ActivityDepreciationType, Core.Domain.ActivityDepreciationType>();
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            return mapper.Map<List<Core.Domain.ActivityDepreciationType>>(efActivityDepriciationType);
        }
    }
```

My task is to scaffold tables in a database in MVC.

Error occurs at line:

```
var efActivityDepriciationType = dbContext.ActivityDepreciationTypes.ToList();
```

This is what the error says:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException occurred   Message=Unable to
>   load the specified metadata resource.   Source=   StackTrace:

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48188389/edit) to show in which line / which part of your code the Exception occurs.

Comment: Check if this similar question will provide you with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1074337/1220550

Comment: i tried deleting the connection strings then deleting the model and adding it again and also tried renaming the edmx . it does not work